# Defining and describing a field extension being normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

My notes by Jens Carsten Jantzen (department of Mathematics at the University of Aarhus) defines a field extension as normal if:

> $N\supset K$ is a normal field extension if for each $\alpha\in N$ the irreducible polynomial for $\alpha$ over $K$ splits over $N$ into linear factors.

Now, I did a search in here before asking, and I have seen various definitions, but no answer to the following question:

> Would it be an accurate description to say that $N\supset K$ is a normal field extension means that the extension field $N$ already contains all roots of all irreducible polynomials of its elements (over $K$)?

This may be a simple question. On the other hand I may have misunderstood the definition. Could someone please confirm or put things straight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, but there is a subtlety about your second definition:

Formally, before the characterization makes sense, we have to embed $N$ into a fixed algebraic closure $L$ of $K$ (that is, an algebraic field extension L|N|K were every polynomial of $K$ splits in linear factors in $L$). If we have fixed such a closure, then the two statements are equivalent:

Let N|K be a normal extension, and $\alpha$ be any element of $N$. Then the minimal polynomial $f_{\alpha}$ of $\alpha$ over K splits over N and the roots of the linear factors are exactly the roots of $f_{\alpha}$ in $L$, thus they are already in $N$.

On the other hand, for every $\alpha \in N$ the minimal polynomial $f_\alpha$ splits in linear factors in $L$ (that's the definition of algebraic closure). If all roots of $f_\alpha$ in $L$ are already in $N$, then $f_{\alpha}$ splits already over $N$. Thus, $N$ is normal.

You may wonder why it is so important to choose an algebraic closure before your second statement is a characterization of normal extensions. The subtlety is, that without considering an algebraic closure, there are not "the" roots of $f_\alpha$. As you may expect, two different algebraic closures of $K$ are isomorphic, but the problem is that the isomorphism is *not canonical* (What does *not canonical* mean? For example $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^2+1)$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-1})\subset \Bbb C$ are two isomorphic splitting fields of $X^2+1$ over $\Bbb Q$, but the isomorphism may be given by $X \mapsto \sqrt{-1}$ as well as by $X \mapsto -\sqrt{-1}$, i.e. the isomorphism is not canonical)

Comment: This makes sense!